# jQuery works in one case, but doesn't work in the other case in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found a good example for me in JSFiddle with jQuery validation. But when I made another code on the similarity of the working code - it's dosen't work. What I do wrong?

```
<form method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" name="confPassword" id="confPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
</div>
</form>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validate({
        rules: {

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            confPassword: {
                    minlenth: 2,
                equalTo : "#password"
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

});
```

And connected these plagins:

> jquery.validate.js additional-methods.js bootstrap-combined.min.css
>   bootstrap.min.js

[working code](http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/),
[my code](https://jsfiddle.net/zahaz6eL/1/)

Comment: If you check the console you'll see why your version doesn't work; you're not including jQuery, and the external resources you added are loaded over `http://` URLs. For them to work in jsFiddle you need to use `https://`. Once those config issues are solved it should work, in theory.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and assume your jQuery snippet is not encapsulated with `<script>` tag.

Comment: @jmsweb jsfiddle automatically puts the Javascript code in a `<script>`.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, in the working code in the external resourses added `http://`

Comment: @jmsweb in the working code `<script>` tag also missing

Comment: Your code runs on my local server. However, the email validation do not seem to work as expected. For example, test@test would display 'OK!' but really that is not a valid email address. Although, that was not your issue. The issue you had is JSFiddle not displaying any message for errors. That can be fixed by updating the HTTPS in External Resources. You had HTTP for External Resources and the console output "Blocked loading mixed active content" error for external resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind about accessing protocol, your JSFiddle is accessing through HTTPS protocol.

### Your JSFiddle

- Your JSFiddle had external resources with HTTP protocol. I would suggest updating the resources to use HTTPS, not HTTP, protocol because the console output from JSFiddle display `Blocked loading mixed active content` error.
- Be sure your JSFiddle JavaScript option should load jQuery. You can select the option that fits your requirement.

*Alternatively, you could access your JSFiddle through HTTP protocol: `http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/`.*

### Local Server

To work on local server, I would suggest download a copy of each external resource and save in a folder accessible to web application as shown in the screenshot and update the `<head>` tag to include `<script>` and `<link/>` tags for loading external resources.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test-web/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test-web/scripts/jquery/jquery.validate-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test-web/scripts/jquery/additional-methods-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test-web/scripts/jquery/bootstrap-combined.min-2.3.2.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/test-web/scripts/jquery/bootstrap.min-2.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

*Alternatively, you could use the URL to use for `src` or `href` attributes to fetch external resources from the Internet*.

[image]

This worked on my local server as shown below. Please let us know whether this worked out on your end.

**Wrong Email**

[image]

**Correct Email**

[image]

Comment: how can I add bootstrap with HTTP protocol? when I found bootstrap-combined.min.css in Plunker I go to the website http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css

Comment: Try accessing your JSFiddle through HTTP protocol, i.e., http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/. It should work.

Comment: Yes, it works there, but when I add the code in my app - it doesn't work. And I want tot understand how in works in that example

Comment: I've update my answer to your question. Please let us know whether this worked on your end.

Comment: works without one action - aaa@aa - valid email, but in the example only aaa@aa.a - correct email

Comment: You could be using mixed version that do not work between jQuery and Bootstrap. I've updated my snippet and posted a new screenshot. I suggest you copying `jquery-1.11.1.js`, `jquery.validate-1.11.1.js`, `additional-methods-1.11.1.js`, `bootstrap-combined.min-2.3.2.css`, and `bootstrap.min-2.3.2.js` as shown on the updated screenshot.